# iOS 10 is it possible to schedule a remote notification?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, scheduler

Is it possible to schedule a remote notification in iOS 10?

I understand it is possible with local notifications but I need to be able to do it remotely.

I want to be able to schedule a notification on my phone (like a reminder) that will activate on another iPhone.

Effectively scheduling notifications for other users.

Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: You need to make an API call from device A, from where you want to schedule a notification and then you can pass this data to other devices using silent push or normal push notifications.

Comment: thanks @CodeGuru, I'll look into silent push notifications.

Comment: You can send a push from one device to another via a server. However you cannot schedule that to occur (you could when the app is in the foreground, but not in the background, see the multitude of past questions about scheduling in the background for more details).